# Extract Facebook Public Page Followers List using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, data-analysis

As of Current Date is it Possible to Fetch List of Followers Id From a Public Page using Graph API.If So which is the Suitable method used.

Is Page Access Token Mandatory to do so?

If yes How do I get One for a Public Page?

Please do provide a reliable answer with a Source .

Thank You

Comment: No, that is not possible. You'll have to take the lack of any documentation saying otherwise as "source" here though, because features that don't exist aren't written down.

Answer (score -1):

Using an access token from the Facebook Graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, with access scope which includes user likes, I am using the following code to try to get all the likes of a user profile:

```
myfbgraph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
mylikes = myfbgraph.get_connections(id="me", connection_name="likes")['data']
for like in mylikes:
  print like['name'], like['followers']
  ...
```

Comment: Using This is it possible to retrieve data from a public page?
ex:coca cola official page

Comment: No that is not possible